# change the value of and id 2 times in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that changes a formula in a form.

The 1st and 2nd parts of the code works fine, but I cannot get the last `if` statement to work properly.

Can someone please help me figure out why the `if {length.value >= 12)` at the bottom will not change the shown `lengthft.value` and `lengthin.value`?

```
lengthft = document.getElementById('lengthft');
lengthin = document.getElementById('lengthin');

length = ((quantity / width)/1);
lengthft = lengthft.value = (Math.floor(length)/1);
lengthin = lengthin.value = (Math.ceil(((((length) - lengthft) * 100)/8).toFixed(2)));

if (lengthin.value >= 12) {
    lengthft = lengthft.value = (lengthft + 1);
    lengthin = lengthin.value = (lengthin - 12);
}
```

Comment: by the way... `lengthft = lengthft.value = (Math.floor(length)/1);` is *reassigning* a number to `lengthft` which is presumably supposed to hold an element

Comment: Yes, the mathfloor portion works as expected. Are you saying that I need to make a new variable to store the new result?

Comment: What I'm saying is that `Math.floor` returns a number, which you then assign to `lengthft.value`, which is alright - but then you assign that number to `lengthft`. So then when you do `lengthft.value` in the `if` statement, it's trying to access the `value` property of a *number* which won't work. Why do you do `lengthft = lengthft.value = ...`? Second, it would help to specify what you mean by "I cannot get the last `if` statement to work". Is the code in the `if` block executing and you're getting an error, or is it not executing at all?

Comment: Without the lengthft.value, the numbers in the form do not change. The code in the if statement is either not executing at all or does not change the numbers in the form. I cannot tell 100%.

Comment: If you `console.log(lengthin.value)` before the if statement what shows in the console?
Also @pushkin has it right, you need to modify the code from `lengthft = lengthft.value = (Math.floor(length)/1);`  to  `lengthft.value = (Math.floor(length)/1);`

Comment: @hajile78 Actually since OP is doing the same thing to `lengthin`, `lengthin.value` would necessarily crash

Comment: I got it working. I did have to fix the length.value. Then change all of the formulas to accept length.value/1 to make it a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it should look like. (see code between *'s)

```
let quantity = 13;
let width = 2;  
lengthft = document.getElementById('lengthft');
lengthin = document.getElementById('lengthin');

length = ((quantity / width)/1);
lengthft.value = (Math.floor(length)/1);
lengthin.value = (Math.ceil(((((length) - *lengthft.value*) * 100)/8).toFixed(2)));

if (lengthin.value >= 12) {
    lengthft = lengthft.value = (lengthft + 1);
    lengthin = lengthin.value = (lengthin - 12);
}
```

Comment: I had to add /1 on all of the .value sections, but more or less the same.

Comment: Also the lengthft/in reassignment in the `if` block should probably be fixed